# Scroll wheel behaving erratically

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/581311/erratic-mouse-scroll-wheel), but I was wondering if there was a fix specific to my mouse.

I have a perixx mx-2200 mouse, and the scroll wheel is being erratic - jumping up, down, ignoring the scroll, depending on how it feels. I can't see an easy way to remove the wheel to clean it, or it's housing.

Is there any software fix (I doubt it, but I'm always hopeful), or does anyone know of a way for me to dismantle it so I can clean it? Or is it just a case of getting a new mouse?

Edit for those wondering - I wound out getting a new mouse

Comment: This is really hard for us to answer I think. The only advice is, if you're prepared to buy a new mouse, try to clean it first in case you get lucky!

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I've got a feeling that might be the outcome. I think I'll give it a couple of days, but I'll accept a "give it up, get out your wallet" answer after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the latest drivers.

This is hard to solve but I would:

Try the mouse on another computer, if the issue continues you have a definte answer. If it doesn't then it could be software/driver related.

Try a different mouse on your computer. I would be amazed if the issue persists but it could do.